# VBA "subscript out of range" error #9: no worksheet involved, method not found

Tags: vba, methods, range, subscript

This isn't like other problems I've seen posts on with this error.  The worksheet isn't directly referenced by my method; the method is present and compiles properly, but I get a runtime error when referencing it.  Details:

My VBA program compiles, but fails at runtime when I try to access a specific method. It doesn't seem to matter whether I set the method up as a function or a property get.

Here is the code fragment which calls the method:

```
Function roots() As Variant ' array of variant(string, double or ratio): real roots only
  Dim fs() As MPolyFactor
  Dim f As Polynomial
  Dim result() As Variant
  Dim nFactors As Integer, i As Integer

  traceIn "entered roots; me = " & Me.toString() & "; f = " & stringify(f)
  On Error Resume Next
  ReDim result(1 To Me.degree) As Variant
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      trace "roots: redim result: " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
      Err.Clear
    End If
  Err.Clear
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    trace "roots: Cannot clear Err: " & Err.Source & ": " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
  End If
  fs = getPFactor
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      trace "roots: fs = getPFactor: " & Err.Source & ": " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
      Err.Clear
    End If
```

(the method continues beyond this, of course, but the rest is irrelevant).

The getPFactor method, which is physically in the same class module but before the above, starts with:

```
Function getPFactor() As Variant ' mPolyFactor()
  traceIn "Entering getPFactor; me = " & Me.toString() & "; dim f(" & LBound(f) & " to " & UBound(f) & ")"
```

My immediate window's trace includes:

```
                        entered roots; me = x - 5; f = Nothing
                          roots: fs = getPFactor: VBAProject: 9: Subscript out of range
```

The tracing functions referenced are in a code module which starts with:

```
Option Explicit
Public indent As Integer

Sub trace(str As String)
  Debug.Print Spc(indent); str
End Sub

Sub traceIn(str As String)
  trace (str)
  indent = indent + 2
End Sub

Sub traceOut(str As String)
  trace (str)
  indent = indent - 2
End Sub
```

Any ideas? I've been trying to figure this out for far too many hours on my own.

Bruce

Comment: What's the value of `Me.degree` when it errors ? It it's a number less than one (or rounds to that) then you'd get the error you're seeing.

Comment: Originally, 5.  I just tried with 2; same result.

Comment: Is it possible the error is coming from somewhere other than the `Redim` line? Try commenting out the `On Error Resume Next` and see if that line raises an error.

Comment: I don't think that the error is on the Redim -- it's on the   
    `fs = getPFactor`
line.  I tried your suggestion in case I'm wrong, though; the 'roots' method silently fails.  Output is:


`Entered showroots; str = x2-1
  entered roots; me = x² - 1; f = Nothing`

That silent failing is why I'm relying so heavily on tracing instead of the debugger -- if I step through the code, it works properly (which I should have mentioned up front), while if I run it, it terminates silently and the watch window is cleared.

Comment: How does `getPFactor` have access to `f`? And `f` (at least as defined in `roots`) is not an array so you can't pass it to LBound() or UBound().

Comment: What is the setting in the VBE under Tools>Options>General>Error trapping? without an "on error..." code should not silently fail.

Comment: AHA!

You asked the right question.  'f' was a private variable within the Polynomial class containing getPFactor.  It was also a private Polynomial object in the roots() method.  I haven't figured out how yet, but this combination was messing things up; getPFactor uses the  class variable version of 'f'.  I don't see why that matters; 'roots' never needed to access the class variable.  But, it did.

Suddenly things are working much better...

Error trapping is set to "Break on unhandled errors", by the way.  The result of invoking 'roots' had always lead to a "VALUE" error in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Ran out of space in my last comment:  THANK YOU.